# Switch 3 pole wiring

Tags: switches

I am trying to make simple switch pedal. I need 3 pole switch to toggle between two left inputs for each right output. Inputs and outputs are mono jacks connecting guitar pedals. Is this schematic correct? Is my wiring drawing correct?

[image: Scheme]

Last third set of input and outputs is missing on drawing but I will probably need it as well.

Comment: The connection is electrically correct. But I would place dummy-load resistors (e.g. 10k) for each left-side output so that the output does not float when not in the signal path.

Comment: I don't know which side will be output. I may need one side to be switch between two outputs and one input or two inputs and one output.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's a good practice to use dummy loads for "inputs" as well. Remember that most pedals (especially overdrive/distortion) have amplifiers inside and they tend to pick up hum when there's a loose, floating cable.